# Biztalk Sendport flat file assembler document spec

Tags: biztalk

Is it necessary to specify the document spec in SendPort flat file assembler property?

I have read some article saying it is NOT necssary as it will use the xml namespace to find the corresponding flat file schema to assemble the xml into flat file.

However, I have tried in our case (we are using 2006R2), but seems it is not ok, we need to specify the document spec in sendport assembler component property to make it works. Otherwise, it will say cannot find the schema from the target namespace.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not required to set the DocumentSpec for the Flat File Assembler.

FFDasm will first attempt to resolve the schema by the same process as the XmlAssembler, usually by namespace#rootnodename.

However, the same rules still apply and the most important is that the namespace#rootnodename must be unique within the BizTalk Group.

So, first, make sure only one of your FF schema is deployed.